# How to convert string to uint8_t in C++?

Tags: c++

How to convert string to uint8_t in C++?

```
std::string str = "b2d";
static const uint8_t PublicKeyData[3] = ??? // it should be like 0x62 0x32 0x64}
```

Comment: Where do you get those values (`0x30, 0x81, 0x9D`)?

Comment: @françois-andrieux `static const uint8_t PublicKeyData[3] = { 0x30, 0x81, 0x9D };
const std::string PublicKey = std::string((const char *)PublicKeyData, 3);
CryptoPP::StringSource source(PublicKey, true);`

Comment: Do you want to get the equivalent ASCII values of each element of the string?

Comment: What are you asking for? What is `{0x30, 0x81, 0x9D}`? Those are not ASCII codes of `"b2d"`.

Comment: @deidei Yes. I want to get ASCII hex values of each element of the string.

Comment: `std::copy(str.begin(), str.end(), PublicKeyData);`

Comment: @LightAlex: that still won't produce `0x30 0x81 0x9D` from `"b2d"`, which would be `0x62 0x32 0x64` instead. So what are you REALLY trying to do? What does `0x30 0x81 0x9D` actually represent? A hash maybe? You need to provide more details about what you are trying to accomplish. What are you going to use the `StringSource` for?

Comment: @remy-lebeau i'm sorry, you are right, 0x62 0x32 0x64, my mistake

Comment: @LightAlex: in that case, `memcpy(PublicKeyData, str.c_str(), 3)` or `std::copy(str.begin(), str.end(), PublicKeyData);` will suffice, provided `str` and `PublicKeyData` have the same number of `char`s (which they do in your example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy all the string characters using the [std::copy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) function:

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdint>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::string str = "b2d";
    uint8_t PublicKeyData[3];
    std::copy(str.begin(), str.end(), PublicKeyData);
}
```

Your array will then hold the following values with the hexadecimal representation: `0x62`, `0x32`, `0x64` or the decimal equivalent: `98`, `50`, `100`. Since the largest value is `100` which is less than `127` your array might have been a simple `char` instead:

```
char PublicKeyData[3];
```